# (Python)Guys plz help!I use selenium for making a simple bot(for yt)...and at the second button it says me list index out of range..the first runs ok

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium, button

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("link from chrome")

submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dismiss-button"]/yt-button-renderer/a')[0]

submit_button.click()

time.sleep(5)

submit_button2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span')[0]
```

#so here at the second button it says me that the list index is out of range..the program runs #with no problem but the second button doesnt work and it says me list index out of range
#the first button runs well..
submit_button2.click()

#please guys any help is acceptable!!!!

```
print (driver.title)
print (driver.current_url)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the right xpath and if so check if it's under any iframes.

Comment: Add jor HTML code, so we can help.